# How to Fix Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>' ,this is use framework7-svelte cli

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

[This Bug module.exports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCz77.png)

[this webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlhAp.jpg)
babel

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `import` and `module.exports`.

Comment: thank you,if i only use module.exports ,, is it possible? what resolve?